# which is better using k means or k means ++ in data clustering and why

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, data-visualization

I have seen that k means ++ is better than k means algorithm, in data clustering ?
In data mining, k-means++ is an algorithm for choosing the initial values (or "seeds") for the k-means clustering algorithm.
Is that true?  please if not say why ?

thanks

Comment: it is too board! either narrow it down, or ask question in some related forums!

Answer (score 0):

Differences in k-means and k-means++ in the initial stages that make cluster centers initialization more "stable" (minimize the intra-class variance).

Answer (score 0):

k means ++ is not a totally different algorithm. k-means++ merely chooses initial centers in a way that gives a provable upper bound and other parts remain the same. And depending on your needs, it could be better or worse. It is up to you to say WHY it is better or not.